# Scroll only horizontally with two y axis with differentes scales

Tags: ios, core-plot

I have a graph wtih scatter plot and barplot and I have two y axis. I wnt to be able to scroll horizontally without the y axes moves. When I have only one y axis my code works but when I add the second one. The second still moving up and down. Have you some idee?

Here is my code :

```
-(void) configureAxes:(CPTGraphHostingView *)layerHostingView withTheme:(CPTTheme *)theme{
    [super configureAxes:layerHostingView withTheme:theme];
    CPTXYAxisSet *axisSet = (CPTXYAxisSet *) layerHostingView.hostedGraph.axisSet;
    CPTAxis *x = axisSet.xAxis;
    CPTAxis *y = axisSet.yAxis;
    y.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyAutomatic;
    x.labelingPolicy= CPTAxisLabelingPolicyNone;
    NSMutableSet *xLabels = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:self.selectedExplYear.exploitation.count];
    NSMutableSet *xLocations = [NSMutableSet setWithCapacity:self.selectedExplYear.exploitation.count];

    for (int i = 0; i<self.selectedExplYear.exploitation.count; i++) {
        SCExploitation *tech = self.selectedExplYear.exploitation[i];
        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [df setDateFormat:@"MMMM"];
        NSDate *dateExploitation = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:tech.exploitationDate.doubleValue/1000];
        NSString *mois = [df stringFromDate:dateExploitation];
        CPTAxisLabel *label = [[CPTAxisLabel alloc]initWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", mois] textStyle:x.labelTextStyle];
        CGFloat location = i;
        label.tickLocation = CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(location);
        label.offset = x.majorTickLength;
        if (label) {
            [xLabels addObject:label];
            [xLocations addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location]];
        }

    }
    NSNumberFormatter *Xformatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [Xformatter setGeneratesDecimalNumbers:NO];
    [Xformatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    y.labelFormatter = Xformatter;
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) layerHostingView.hostedGraph.defaultPlotSpace;
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTitleStyle = [CPTMutableTextStyle textStyle];
    axisTitleStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTitleStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTitleStyle.fontSize = 14.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *axisLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    axisLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    axisLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    CPTMutableTextStyle *axisTextStyle = [[CPTMutableTextStyle alloc] init];
    axisTextStyle.color = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    axisTextStyle.fontName = @"Helvetica-Bold";
    axisTextStyle.fontSize = 14.0f;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *tickLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor whiteColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.0f;
    tickLineStyle.lineColor = [CPTColor blackColor];
    tickLineStyle.lineWidth = 1.0f;

    x.axisLabels=xLabels;
    x.majorTickLocations = xLocations;
    axisSet.yAxis.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithLowerOffset:5];
    y.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(250)];

    CPTXYAxis *y2 = [[CPTXYAxis alloc] init];
    y2.coordinate = CPTCoordinateY;
    y2.plotSpace = self.scatterGraphPlotSpace;
    y2.axisConstraints = [CPTConstraints constraintWithUpperOffset:0];
    y2.labelingPolicy = CPTAxisLabelingPolicyFixedInterval;
    y2.axisLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y2.majorTickLineStyle = axisLineStyle;
    y2.title = @"Km";
    y2.majorIntervalLength = CPTDecimalFromFloat((80 - 0) / 5.0f);
    y2.labelFormatter = Xformatter;
    y2.titleTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    y2.labelTextStyle = axisTextStyle;
    y2.tickDirection               = CPTSignNone;
    y2.tickLabelDirection          = CPTSignPositive;
    y2.orthogonalCoordinateDecimal = CPTDecimalFromFloat(5.0);
    y2.titleOffset                 = 16.0 * CPTFloat(-2.1);
    y2.visibleRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0.0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(80)];

    self.scatterGraphPlotSpace.xRange = plotSpace.xRange;
    layerHostingView.hostedGraph.axisSet.axes = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:x, y, y2, nil];


}


-(void)configurePlots:(CPTGraphHostingView *)layerHostingView withTheme:(CPTTheme *)theme
{
    CPTGraph *graph = layerHostingView.hostedGraph;
    CPTBarPlot *barPlotTotalDetenteEau = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor blueColor] horizontalBars:NO];
    barPlotTotalDetenteEau.identifier = DETENTEEAUIDENTIFIER;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lsEauPotable = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc]init];
    lsEauPotable.lineColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];
    lsEauPotable.lineWidth = 0.5;
    barPlotTotalDetenteEau.lineStyle = lsEauPotable;
    barPlotTotalDetenteEau.dataSource =self;
    barPlotTotalDetenteEau.delegate = self;
    barPlotTotalDetenteEau.zPosition = 90;
    barPlotTotalDetenteEau.labelOffset = LABELOFFSET;
    barPlotTotalDetenteEau.title = NSLocalizedString(@"exploitation_detente_eau", nil);
    barPlotTotalDetenteEau.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(BARWIDTH);
    barPlotTotalDetenteEau.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0);
    [graph addPlot:barPlotTotalDetenteEau toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];


    CPTBarPlot *barPlotTotalControleGaz = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor yellowColor] horizontalBars:NO];
    barPlotTotalControleGaz.identifier = CONTROLEGAZIDENTIFIER;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lsNouveau = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc]init];
    lsNouveau.lineColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];
    lsNouveau.lineWidth = 0.5;
    barPlotTotalControleGaz.lineStyle = lsNouveau;
    barPlotTotalControleGaz.dataSource =self;
    barPlotTotalControleGaz.delegate = self;
    barPlotTotalControleGaz.zPosition = 100;
    barPlotTotalControleGaz.labelOffset = LABELOFFSET;
    barPlotTotalControleGaz.title = NSLocalizedString(@"exploitation_controle_gaz", nil);
    barPlotTotalControleGaz.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(BARWIDTH);
    barPlotTotalControleGaz.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromDouble(BARWIDTH+0.01);
    [graph addPlot:barPlotTotalControleGaz toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];


    self.scatterGraphPlotSpace = [[CPTXYPlotSpace alloc] init];
    self.scatterGraphPlotSpace.allowsUserInteraction =YES;
    // self.scatterGraphPlotSpace.delegate =self;
    CPTScatterPlot *controlerPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    controlerPlot.dataSource = self;
    controlerPlot.delegate = self;
    controlerPlot.title = NSLocalizedString(@"km_fuite", nil);
    controlerPlot.identifier = KMCONTROLERIDENTIFIER;
    controlerPlot.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection = 15.0f;
    CPTColor *effectivePlotColor = [CPTColor redColor];
    [graph addPlot:controlerPlot toPlotSpace:self.scatterGraphPlotSpace];

    CPTBarPlot *barPlotTotalControleEau = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor greenColor] horizontalBars:NO];
    barPlotTotalControleEau.identifier = CONTROLEEAUIDENTIFIER;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lsProvisoire = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc]init];
    lsProvisoire.lineColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];
    lsProvisoire.lineWidth = 0.5;
    barPlotTotalControleEau.lineStyle = lsProvisoire;
    barPlotTotalControleEau.dataSource = self;
    barPlotTotalControleEau.delegate = self;
    barPlotTotalControleEau.zPosition = 100;
    barPlotTotalControleEau.labelOffset = LABELOFFSET;
    barPlotTotalControleEau.title = NSLocalizedString(@"exploitation_controle_eau", nil);
    barPlotTotalControleEau.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(BARWIDTH);
    barPlotTotalControleEau.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromDouble(0);
    [graph addPlot:barPlotTotalControleEau toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];

    CPTBarPlot *barPlotTotalDetenteGaz = [CPTBarPlot tubularBarPlotWithColor:[CPTColor grayColor] horizontalBars:NO];
    barPlotTotalDetenteGaz.identifier = DETENTEGAZIDENTIFIER;
    CPTMutableLineStyle *lsAugmentation = [[CPTMutableLineStyle alloc]init];
    lsAugmentation.lineColor = [CPTColor lightGrayColor];
    lsAugmentation.lineWidth = 0.5;
    barPlotTotalDetenteGaz.lineStyle = lsAugmentation;
    barPlotTotalDetenteGaz.dataSource =self;
    barPlotTotalDetenteGaz.delegate = self;
    barPlotTotalDetenteGaz.zPosition = 70;
    barPlotTotalDetenteGaz.labelOffset = LABELOFFSET;
    barPlotTotalDetenteGaz.title = NSLocalizedString(@"exploitation_detente_gaz", nil);
    barPlotTotalDetenteGaz.barWidth = CPTDecimalFromDouble(BARWIDTH);
    barPlotTotalDetenteGaz.barOffset = CPTDecimalFromDouble(BARWIDTH+0.01);
    [graph addPlot:barPlotTotalDetenteGaz toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];

    NSArray *plots = @[barPlotTotalDetenteEau,barPlotTotalControleEau,barPlotTotalControleGaz,barPlotTotalDetenteGaz];
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;
    [plotSpace scaleToFitPlots:plots];
    CPTMutablePlotRange *xRange = [plotSpace.xRange mutableCopy];
    [xRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.3f)];
    xRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(-0.5f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(4.0f)];

    plotSpace.xRange = xRange;
    CPTMutablePlotRange *yRange = [plotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
    [yRange expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.4f)];
    plotSpace.yRange = yRange;
    plotSpace.delegate = self;

    self.scatterGraphPlotSpace.globalYRange = plotSpace.globalYRange;
    CPTScatterPlot *visuelPlot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] init];
    visuelPlot.dataSource = self;
    visuelPlot.delegate = self;
    visuelPlot.title = NSLocalizedString(@"km_visuel", nil);
    visuelPlot.identifier = KMVISUELIDENTIFIER;
    visuelPlot.plotSymbolMarginForHitDetection = 15.0f;
    CPTColor *budgeteePlotColor = [CPTColor orangeColor];


    CPTMutableLineStyle *budgeteelLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle]; // [budgeteePlot.dataLineStyle mutableCopy];
    budgeteelLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
    budgeteelLineStyle.lineColor = budgeteePlotColor;
    visuelPlot.dataLineStyle = budgeteelLineStyle;
    CPTPlotSymbol *budgeteeSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    budgeteeSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:budgeteePlotColor];
    budgeteeSymbol.lineStyle = budgeteelLineStyle;
    budgeteeSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    visuelPlot.plotSymbol = budgeteeSymbol;

    CPTMutableLineStyle *effectiveLineStyle = [CPTMutableLineStyle lineStyle];
    effectiveLineStyle.lineWidth = 2.5;
    effectiveLineStyle.lineColor = effectivePlotColor;
    controlerPlot.dataLineStyle = effectiveLineStyle;
    CPTPlotSymbol *effectiveSymbol = [CPTPlotSymbol ellipsePlotSymbol];
    effectiveSymbol.fill = [CPTFill fillWithColor:effectivePlotColor];
    effectiveSymbol.lineStyle = effectiveLineStyle;
    effectiveSymbol.size = CGSizeMake(6.0f, 6.0f);
    controlerPlot.plotSymbol = effectiveSymbol;
    [self.scatterGraphPlotSpace scaleToFitPlots:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:controlerPlot, visuelPlot, nil]];
    [graph addPlot:visuelPlot toPlotSpace:self.scatterGraphPlotSpace];


    CPTPlotRange *globalYRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromDouble(0) length:CPTDecimalFromDouble(250)];
    plotSpace.globalYRange = globalYRange;
    self.scatterGraphPlotSpace.yRange =[CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0)
                                                                    length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(80)];
    CPTMutablePlotRange *y2Range = [self.scatterGraphPlotSpace.yRange mutableCopy];
    [y2Range expandRangeByFactor:CPTDecimalFromCGFloat(1.4f)];
    self.scatterGraphPlotSpace.yRange = y2Range;

    [layerHostingView.hostedGraph addPlotSpace:self.scatterGraphPlotSpace];
}

-(void)configureGraph:(CPTGraphHostingView *)layerHostingView withTheme:(CPTTheme *)theme
{

    CPTGraph *graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:layerHostingView.bounds];
    graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder = NO;
    layerHostingView.hostedGraph = graph;
    if(self.selectedExplYear.exploitation.count> 3){
        graph.defaultPlotSpace.allowsUserInteraction = YES;
    }
    [graph applyTheme:self.theme];
    graph.paddingBottom = 60.0f;
    graph.paddingLeft = 30.0f;
    graph.paddingTop = 30.0f;
    graph.paddingRight = 30.0f;
    graph.title = nil;

}


-(CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)displacement
{
    return CGPointMake(displacement.x, 0);
}

-(CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate
{
    if (space == self.scatterGraphPlotSpace) {
        if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateY) {
            newRange = self.scatterGraphPlotSpace.yRange;
        }
    }else{
        if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateY) {
            newRange = ((CPTXYPlotSpace*)space).yRange;
        }
    }
    return newRange;
}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You'll get a better response if you frame your question a little more clearly. Specifically, not just dropping a code dump and a vague problem specification. Try and get it down to a minimal, complete, verifiable example.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `delegate` for `self.scatterGraphPlotSpace`. That line of code is commented out in the code you posted.